# How can I use Webpack to load a separate JS file in Shopware 6 and improve web performance?

Tags: performance, webpack, shopware, shopware6, web-performance

How to load a separate JS file in Shopware 6 using webpack?

## What?

I'm trying to load a separate javascript file next to the all.js file by using WebPack.

## Why?

The all.js file can get really big and you're loading unnecessary javascript on a page. So by using code splitting (which should be possible since WebPack is implemented in Shopware 6) and dynamic imports you could stop loading unnecessary javascript.

## What I've tried

I've added a webpack.config.js file inside the root of my theme plugin like so:

```
module.exports = {

    entry: {
        main: './src/main.js', 
        separateFile: './src/js/separate.js'
    },

    output: {
        filename: '[name].js'
    },

    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all',
        },
    },
};
```

After running `bin/build-storefront.sh` there is no separate JS file added in the public folder.

I'm also trying to dynamically load this JS file in src/Resources/app/storefront/src/main.js but this results in a 404 since the separate file doesn't exist.

### Edit:

If someone lands on this post and wants to know more about this topic: [Async JavaScript and get rid of the all.js in the Storefront](https://github.com/shopware/shopware/discussions/3310)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work since all pre-compiled assets of plugins are collected in the [`ThemeCompiler`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/75f3ba3ae463801a043d5ca79727babcfaaa1eea/src/Storefront/Theme/ThemeCompiler.php#L423) and concatenated into one single script. This is done  in PHP since node is not a requirement for production environments.

You could try to add separate scripts as additional [custom assets](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-custom-assets), but you would still have to extend the template to add the corresponding `script` tags manually.